# grep rpms including summary

Tags: grep, rpm

To grep through rpms I usually do, for example

```
$ rpm -qa | grep gimp
gimp-libs-2.10.32-3.fc37.x86_64
gimp-2.10.32-3.fc37.x86_64
gmic-gimp-3.1.6-2.fc37.x86_64
```

But I would like to include 'Summary' description as well:

```
gimp-libs-2.10.32-3.fc37.x86_64         GIMP libraries
gimp-2.10.32-3.fc37.x86_64              GNU Image Manipulation Program
gmic-gimp-3.1.6-2.fc37.x86_64           G'MIC plugin for GIMP
```

I tried using xargs and awk:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep gimp | xargs rpm -qi | awk -- '/^Summary/{$1="";$2="";print}'
```

but this displays summaries only :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
rpm -qa gimp --queryformat '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}-%{ARCH}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'
```

See: `man rpm` and `rpm --querytags`